# Is there a better way to debug HighCharts issues

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I stumbled into this issue, where i was generating an image using Highcharts and PhantomJS. URL: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs

I was using the JSON:

```
{'series': [{'data': [10, 9, 7, 4]}], 'chart': {'type': 'bar'}, 'xAxis': {'categories': ['5 - 10', '11 - 16', '17 - 22', '23 - 28']}, 'title': {'text': u'HistoData'}};
```

PhantomJS threw errors telling:
SyntaxError: Parse error

Highcharts.customCode.parsed

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: options

phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():63
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():132
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():132
```

Now, it took me a while to figure out, that the correct JSON was:

```
{'series': [{'data': [10, 9, 7, 4]}], 'chart': {'type': 'bar'}, 'xAxis': {'categories': ['5 - 10', '11 - 16', '17 - 22', '23 - 28']}, 'title': {'text': 'HistoData'}};
```

Now, there is no direct link to the error and the fix. Is there a better way to debug syntax issues ? It would be a pain in the ass to figure out what went wrong with the JSON chart data otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure how highcharts works, but this is not valid JSON. Change `'` to `"` and remove the `;` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a json validator tool to make sure your json is in the correct format. e.g. http://jsonlint.com/